# Encrypt Query string for DataNavigateUrlFormatString in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, query-string

What I want here is I want to encrypt the querystring which is being formed by using `asp.net Gridview`.

Below is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCreatedCRList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover"
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" EmptyDataText="No data to display.">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="CHANGEREQUESTNUMBER" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow"
                        HeaderText="Change Request No" DataNavigateUrlFields="CHANGEREQUESTID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ChangeRequestDetails.aspx?ID={0}"
                        Text="CR No" Target="_blank" ItemStyle-Width="11%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="Description"
                        ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="STATENAME" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="State"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="State" ItemStyle-Width="12%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CITYNAME" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="City"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="City" ItemStyle-Width="7%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CATEGORY" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="Category"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Category" ItemStyle-Width="7%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CHANGETYPE" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="Type"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Type" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OPENCLOSED" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="Open/ Closed"
                        ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="4%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="Detailed Status"
                        ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="15%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATEDON" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="Creation Date"
                        ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="7%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LASTMODIFIEDON" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRow" HeaderText="Last Modified Date"
                        ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="7%" />
                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#C3C1C1" />
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="pagergrid" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

I want to encrypt `DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ChangeRequestDetails.aspx?ID={0}"`

Comment: Just use `NavigateUrl='<%# this.ResolveUrl(string.Format("ChangeRequestDetails.aspx?ID={0}", Decrypt(Eval("CHANGEREQUESTID").ToString()))) %>'`. (`Decrypt` is custom encryption method name example).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: Hi, But I guess first it needs to be encrypted right ?

Comment: Of course it should be encrypted before `ResolveUrl` can work with ciphered ID.

Comment: I am getting build error as `Error 2 Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event. D:\Username\CMP\CMP\CMPNew CR PDF\ChangeRequestApplication\Homepage.aspx 172 `

Comment: Instead of `HyperLinkField`, try `ItemTemplate` filled with `HyperLink` where `Eval` expression works well.

Comment: Well thanks it is more clear way. :) but with this code, I am getting error as `Error 4 The name 'Decrypt' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Of course you should change `Decrypt` to your own function name which decrypting the ID, the method name is just for example :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178906/discussion-between-bnn-and-tetsuya-yamamoto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you had already created a method which returns `string` for encryption/decryption purpose. The method should be accessible from data binding syntax in page markup:

```
public string ParseRequest(string id)
{
    // perform encryption/decryption here
}
```

Note that `HyperLinkField` doesn't support binding with `Eval()` method required for encryption/decryption process (because it will throw *`HyperLinkField` does not have a DataBinding event* message), you need to use `TemplateField` and put `HyperLink` control inside it. Then call encryption/decryption method inside `NavigateUrl` with data binding:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCreatedCRList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" EmptyDataText="No data to display.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="CRNo" runat="server" 
                 NavigateUrl='<%# this.ResolveUrl(
                 string.Format("ChangeRequestDetails.aspx?ID={0}", ParseRequest(Eval("CHANGEREQUESTID").ToString()))) %>' 
                 Text="CR No" Target="_blank" ...>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <%-- other BoundField columns --%>

    </Columns>

    <%-- other settings --%>
</asp:GridView>
```

Or use this way if you want to encrypt entire URL together with query string:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="CRNo" runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl='<%# this.ResolveUrl(ParseRequest(Eval("REQUESTURL").ToString())) %>' Text="CR No" Target="_blank" ...>
</asp:HyperLink>
```